# Highlight selected row in primeng table without checking the checbox

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

I am using primeng `p-table` along with `p-checkbox`. I want to be able to highlight the clicked row (or the row content) without checking the checkbox. The Checkbox should be checked on clicking the checkbox itself, not the row.
I tried using `[pSelectableRow]` but it also checks the checkbox in addition to highlighting it.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="brands" [(selection)]="selected" dataKey="vin">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 3em">
                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
            </th>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

What should I do to only highlight the clicked row, not check the checkbox?
I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-row-highlight?file=src/app/app.component.html) sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by maintaining a variable `highlight` that gets the clicked row value and assigning the highlight class only to rows where this value is equal to that of the clicked row.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr class="some-class"  [class.ui-state-highlight]="rowData === highlighted">
            <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            
                <a (click)="highlighted = rowData"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Updated Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-row-highlight?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: It is not working on stackblitz

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: idea looks good...but how to handle rowSelect & rowUnselect ()?

Answer (score 0):

Add some class on the rows

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" class="some-class">
```

Then in css do the trick

```
.some-class:hover {
  background-color: some color... or put any style you need
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still checks the checkbox and I want it to work on click, not hover.

Comment: Put clickable area inside <label for "checkbox"> or add another hidden checkbox for that label, it can do the trick without clicking the checkbox only, but entire row

Comment: This isn't very clear to me. Can you update the Stackblitz example please?